# VLC Player not working properly in one computer

Tags: vlc, rtsp

I have a strange problem. I have 2 computers, both with windows 10. I am connecting to an IP cam using rtsp protocol but only one computer connects and plays the video without problems, using VLC player. I don't know why the other computer doesn't play it. It looks like it connects to it because I am asked for the user and passoword, but after no video is played. The issue gets even more strange because if I use a different cam, of a different brand, I can see the video playing in both computers without any issues. I have only issues with one brand and only in one computer! I am totally lost.
I have just tested also with a third computer and it works without issues. I have already unistall and reinstall the latest VLC player version but nothing works.

Please help.
Thanks,
Julio